# How can I save captured image via the camera in external storage?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-fileprovider, android-storage

**provider_paths**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

**Manifests**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

**Inside onCreate in MainActivity**

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = null;
try {
    file = File.createTempFile("JPEG_28237424324185", ".jpg", getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (file != null) {
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 100);
}
```

I'm trying to capture an image via the camera and after that save it in external storage but nothing is happening, Why?

Comment: `trying to capture an image via the camera and after that save it in external storage` No you try to capture an image with the camera and let the camera app save the image to a file served by your FileProvider.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you mean with "nothing is happening". The Camera app is not started?

Comment: You shoulf not already create an empty file yourself with createTempFile() as when the user cancels the operation you are left with an empty file.

Comment: @blackapps The camera is working well but after pressing on ok button in preview the image will not store in device storage

Comment: How do you know? Which error message do you get? Which exception is throw? Tell what happens instead! Are you also telling that onActivityResult is not triggered? Tell what happens!

Comment: @blackapps There are no errors during capturing images via the camera even I can show it in Bitmap inside the app but the code above must store captured image in storage.

Comment: Well show your code to get a bitmap. And tell how you know that it is not stored in storage. You cannot get a bitmap if you dont use the stored file for it. You still keep it vague. Why do i have to pull everything out of you?

Comment: @blackapps I have deleted the code that shows the Bitmap in ImageView in the morning but in general, Is the code above look good, or did I miss something? I followed this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics?hl=en#TaskPath)